# Spring 3.1.1 java based configuration issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I have been using the new feature of Spring 3.1.1 the "java based configuration".
I have faced an issue while creating a small demo to test that new concept.

When I deploy my "springway.war" over tomcat ,when I request "http://localhost:8080/springway/" --> I gout "HTTP Status 404"

I am sure that I missing something but I couldn't figure it out .
I have been looking at the "GreenHouse" example that is over Spring site but I still get the same issue.

Here is my WebConfig.java :

```
package config;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;

import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    }


    /**
     * ViewResolver configuration required to work with Tiles2-based views.
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(FreeMarkerView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Configures Tiles at application startup.
     */
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions(new String[]{
                "/WEB-INF/layouts/tiles.xml",
                "/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml"
        });
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return configurer;
    }

//    @Bean
//    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
//        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
//        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath(
//
//                "/WEB-INF/views/**/freemarker.xml");
////        configurer.set(true);
//        return configurer;
//    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

And the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Java-based annotation-driven Spring container definition -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Location of Java @Configuration classes that configure the components that makeup this application -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>config</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies the default mode of this application, to be activated if no other profile (or mode) is specified -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>embedded</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


         <!-- Handles requests into the application -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <!-- No explicit configuration file reference here: everything is configured in the root container for simplicity -->
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I didn`t post it so I  must ask this question. Did you set the @RequestParam in your controller ?

Comment: I have noticed that over the "Green House" there is a class called App Controller that's called when the app starts up.
I assume that is the one that's responsible to scan the controllers.
However when I used this class,it's not called from my demo.
You can see my demo over : http://www.zshare.net/download/994635177102c4ff/

Comment: My main issue is how to scan/configure the controllers using java based configurations !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues I have faced have been resolved.
I have resolved the isse of scanning the controllers via 
"@ComponentScan("my.package.containing.controllers.to.scan")"

You can see the demo here: http://refile.net/f/?o8v